# Async getter function in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, getter

I have a project in Node and Typescript in which I am trying to connect to the mongoose Schema from the property of an object, only if the Schema has the same name as the value of the `name` property

These are the data:

Schema: `const Company = require("../../schemas/companies")`

MENU_PROPERTIES:

```
const MENU_PROPERTIES = [
    {
       "name":"Company",
       "icon":"local_shipping"
    },
    {
       "name":"Client",
       "icon":"people"
    },
    {
       "name":"Employee",
       "icon":"account_circle"
    }
]
```

MenuActions:

```
interface MenuActions {
    name: string,
    icon: string,
    total(): Promise<number>
}
```

This is the first function I've tried:

```
let menuData: MenuActions[] = [];
for (let menu of MENU_PROPERTIES) {
                menuData.push({
                    name: menu.name,
                    icon: menu.icon,
                    get total() {
                        return SCHEMA_LIST.includes(this.name) ? eval(this.name).find().count() : 0
                    }
                })
            }
```

Result: ERROR

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Topology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (C:\Users\quality\Desktop\proyectoFinal\project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\quality\Desktop\proyectoFinal\project-server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at returnHandler (C:\Users\quality\Desktop\proyectoFinal\project-server\build\src\routes.js:148:48)
    at C:\Users\quality\Desktop\proyectoFinal\project-server\build\src\routes.js:132:13
```

This is the second function:

```
let menuData: MenuActions[] = [];
for (let menu of MENU_PROPERTIES) {
                menuData.push({
                    name: menu.name,
                    icon: menu.icon,
                    get total() {
                        return (async () => {
                            return SCHEMA_LIST.includes(this.name) ? await eval(this.name).find().count() : 0
                        }); 
                    }
                })
            }
```

Result: This function does not return anything, the `total` property does not appear in the object

```
[
   {
      "name":"Company",
      "icon":"local_shipping"
   },
   {
      "name":"Client",
      "icon":"people"
   },
   {
      "name":"Employee",
      "icon":"account_circle"
   }
]
```

Comment: JSON supports the [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types): number, string, boolean, array, object and null. You can't store a function in JSON. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you want to serialize a JavaScript object containing a function. That won't work.

Comment: @jabaa What I am trying to do is connect to the mongoose Schema to get the total results. If the list of Schemas (SCHEMA_LIST) contains the value of the property, then it connects with the Schema of mongoose (Company in this case) otherwise, the total property should be 0. I am using Typescript in Node

Comment: The title is _"Async getter function in JSON"_. I'm not sure what it means, but you can't store a getter function in JSON. JSON doesn't support functions.

Comment: @soger if you want to assign value to total, you should define `MenuActions.total` as `number`, and push `total: SCHEMA_LIST.includes(menu.name) ? await eval(menu.name).find().count() : 0`

Comment: The error comes from `at C:\Users\quality\Desktop\proyectoFinal\project-server\build\src\routes.js:132:13`. It looks like you are trying to send a response containing a JavaScript object that can't be serialized because it contains a circular structure. Do you provide the code somewhere in your question?

Comment: Btw, don't use `eval`! If you want to select a collection to query dynamically, put them in a `Map` and look it up.

Comment: @Bergi How can I do that in this case? and why shouldn't I use `eval()`?

Comment: I think you're trying to secure this use of `eval` by prefixing it with `SCHEMA_LIST.includes(name)`. Instead of building a `SCHEMA_LIST = ['Company', 'Client'];` array just build a `SCHEMAS = { 'Company': Company, 'Client': Client }` object, then do `SCHEMAS[name]?.find().count() ?? 0`

Comment: _"why shouldn't I use `eval()`"_: [Never use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

Comment: @jabaa How can I then do the same thing I'm doing with eval?

Comment: Have you opened the link and read the paragraph?

Comment: @jabaa Yes, I've been looking at the documentation, from what I see you have to use property accessors if I'm not mistaken, that's what I'm trying to see if I can get it out